Subprocess throwing error to run a command
I am tring to write a test case where i download a file(PCAP) file, then i save it with name test1.pcap
then i want it to be validated via tshark cli tool,
"tshark -r {} -Y http".format(filename)
``

its says ```
OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')

however the file exists when i check it with os.path.exsists(filename)
My code is:
def test_pcap():

.....
   pcap_response = requests.get(pcap_url)
      assert pcap_response.status_code == 200, "Failed to retrieve PCAP file. Status code: 
{pcap_response.status_code}"
    assert len(pcap_response.content) > 0, "PCAP file is empty"
    print(pcap_response)
    print("PCAP file successfully retrieved.,")

   with open(pcap_file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(pcap_response.content)

   if pcap_file_path is None:
        raise ValueError("PCAP file path is None")

   if not os.path.exists(pcap_file_path):
     print("PCAP file does not exist")
   
   isValid = validate_pcap(pcap_file_path)
   print("pcap validation result is: ",isValid)
   process_pcap(pcap_file_path)
   assert isValid, "Sanitized PCAP file still contains sensitive information."

    


def validate_pcap(pcap_file):
    if not os.path.exists(pcap_file):
        print("File does not exist.", pcap_file)
        return False
    try:
        print("tshark -r {} -Y http".format(pcap_file))
        result = subprocess.Popen(
            ["sudo", "tshark", "-r {}".format(pcap_file), "-Y", "http"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True
        )
        r1, r2 = result.communicate
        print("Next step after result and result is: ", result, r1, r2)
        if result.returncode == 0 and result.stdout:
            print("PCAP file validation passed.")
            print("Output:\n", result.stdout)
            return True
        else:
            print("No matching traffic found or tshark error.")
            print("Error:\n", result.stderr)
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error running tshark:", e)
        return 
    


I believe the "No such file or directory" error refers to the tshark command, not the pcap file.

yeah, you were right, No such file or directory  made me confused for the file path issue

You're not printing the same command line you're actually executing, to begin with. Then, you shouldn't need sudo to run tshark if you already have a capture file.
I would suggest using shutil.which() to find tshark:
tshark = shutil.which("tshark")
if not tshark:
    raise FileNotFoundError("tshark not found")
cmd = [tshark, "-r", pcap_file, "-Y", "http"]
result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, ...


actually the result from sub process was wrong, as tshark was not installed but instead of command not found, it was saying "No such file or directory", which increased my confusion.

"command not found" is something a shell might say, yes, and subprocess isn't one. But this answer addresses that too - you'll get a very clear error if tshark is not available.
